# Don't update avatar image in Django

Tags: django

I would like to update a profile image as if it were not saved in the project. What could be wrong?

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/perfil')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.usuario)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'polls/edit_profile.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(label='Foto de perfil')
            class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name', 'last_name','matricula','email','avatar','tipoUsuario']
```

models.py

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField('Foto de perfil',upload_to='static/img/uploads/profile_photo',default="static/img/user.jpg")
```

Comment: Your are using the Django User Model, not `Usuario` in `forms.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your Usuario Model also.You can try like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
            user = form.save()           
            user.usuario.avatar = avatar
            user.usuario.save()
            return redirect('/perfil')
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks